# Strict Standards: Non-static method spController::getLang() should not be called statically

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
<?PHP
function T($w) {
    $method = $GLOBALS['G_SP']["lang"][spController::getLang()]; // LINE 2
    if(!isset($method) || 'default' == $method){
        return $w;
    }elseif( function_exists($method) ){
        return ( $tmp = call_user_func($method, $w) ) ? $tmp : $w;
    }elseif( is_array($method) ){
        return ( $tmp = spClass($method[0])->{$method[1]}($w) ) ? $tmp : $w;
    }elseif( file_exists($method) ){
        $dict = require($method);
        return isset($dict[$w]) ? $dict[$w] : $w;
    }else{
        return $w;
    }
}
?>
```

no i see this error in line 2:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method spController::getLang() should not
>   be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\spFunctions.php on line 2

how to fix this error?

**NOTE** : i need to fix this without change php.ini (disable error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT OR display_errors = On to Off)

Comment: have you verified that you are calling the method properly? from the error it seems that you should have an instance of spController and call getLang() from it instead of calling it as static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `spController::getLang()` function is not referencing an instance property (using `$this`) then all you need is to add `static` to your function declaration. i.e

```
public static function getLang();
```

or if you are using a reference to `$this` you will need to create an instance of the `pController` and then call the `getLang()` method as a instance method.

```
$controller = new spController();
$lang = $controller->getLang();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sp = new spController();
$sp->getLang();
```

Or maybe an instance of `spController` already exists from somhere in your application